# What maximum and minimum number this MATLAB function normrnd can output?

Tags: probability, matlab, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

What maximum and minimum number this MATLAB function normrnd(mu,sigma) can output? If the mean = 0  and S.D =2? and what happen if we increase the S.D in this fucntion.

Comment: So the sigma in this function is σ. If I say my sigma=2 and mean = 0 than it means that there will be 95% random numbers that will be generated within -4 and 4? and 68% of the random number generated will be between -2 and 2?

Comment: That's correct, but of course only in an approximate sense. The generated numbers are random after all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, there are no such maximum and minimum. A normal (Gaussian) pdf has infinite support, so it can produce any value, no matter how high or low, with positive probability. Of course, exceeding a value *x* is less probable as *x* grows; but the probability is never 0.

In reality, Matlab cannot represent values with absolute value greater than `realmax` (about 10^308). But that's a very large number, and the probability of reaching a value close to that is *very* small.

The S.D is a scale factor of the distribution. A greater S.D. tends to produce random numbers with larger absolute value. You can think about it this way: you generate a number according to a *standard_* normal distribution (0 mean, 1 S.D.), and then you multiply times the actual S.D. and add the actual mean.